# How to implement OpenCL to a program which uses GMP Library? The Kernel Code is not recognizing mpz_class and mpz_invert

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cryptography, opencl, gmp

I am trying to implement OpenCL for a C++ project which uses GMP Library (using Ubuntu). But the Kernel code is not recognizing mpz_class, its variables or any of the GMP functions. It is also not recognizing Strings.

```
1 - error: use of undeclared identifier 'mpz_class'
2 - implicit declaration of function 'mpz_invert' is invalid in OpenCL
```

The .cpp file is compiling with no issues.

```
g++ production_opencl.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 -lgmp -lgmpxx -O3
```

What am i doing wrong here? Anything i missed? If the kernel code does not recognize GMP Library, what are other alternative implementations of OpenCL like with GMP like? Here is the sample code below.

```
#include <CL/opencl.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "gmpxx.h"
#define SIZE 1
using namespace std; 

string kernel_code =
    "void kernel simple_add(global const char* x, global const char* y){ "
    
    "mpz_class data_x;"
    "mpz_class data_y;"
    "mpz_class answer;"
    "//This string is simply there to imply an error that string is not being recognized"
    "string sample = \"\";" 
    "data_x = x[get_global_id(0)];"
    "data_y = y[get_global_id(0)];"
    "answer = data_x + data_y;"
    "   }                                                                               ";


int main()
{
    vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
    if (all_platforms.size() == 0) 
    {
        cout << " No OpenCL platforms found.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];

    vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    if (all_devices.size() == 0) {
        cout << " No devices found.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];
    
    cl::Context context({ default_device });

    cl::Buffer x_d(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(string) * SIZE);
    cl::Buffer y_d(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(string) * SIZE);

    string x_h[SIZE], y_h[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        x_h[i] = "27621303327596518720915888553154295689881592976324299262842891450485737953405";
        y_h[i] = "14987516938962486978304910530259574733284571700592351978564276473985476545831";
    }

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);

    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(x_d, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(string) * SIZE, x_h);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(y_d, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(string) * SIZE, y_h);

    cl::Program::Sources sources;

    sources.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length() });
    cl::Program program(context, sources);

    if (program.build({ default_device }) != CL_SUCCESS) 
    {
        cout << " Error building: " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device) << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    cl::compatibility::make_kernel<cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer> simple_add(cl::Kernel(program, "simple_add"));
    cl::NDRange global(SIZE);
    simple_add(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, global), x_d, y_d).wait();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCL C code ("kernel_code") is completely separate from the C++ code, and it's compiled at runtime. Any header that you include in the C++ code is only valid in the C++ code.

You could place an "#include "gmpxx.h"" in the OpenCL code (include works here too), but OpenCL is C99 and not C++, so it won't work to include any C++ libraries. You can't do classes in OpenCL C, only structs. Also no recursion, no dynamic allocation, no multi-dimensional arrays, no fancy data structures. So you would have to rewrite the required functionality in C99 to have it available on the GPU.

Comment: I think you can have private and local multi-dimensional arrays.